# Count seconds on switch interval SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table like this:

```
Value TimeStamp
1   2016-04-01 00:01:09.000
0   2016-04-01 00:01:09.000
0   2016-04-01 00:01:37.000
1   2016-04-01 00:01:37.000
1   2016-04-01 00:04:52.000
1   2016-04-01 00:09:58.000
1   2016-04-01 00:15:05.000
1   2016-04-01 00:20:11.000
1   2016-04-01 00:24:49.000
1   2016-04-01 00:29:55.000
1   2016-04-01 00:31:19.000
0   2016-04-01 00:31:19.000
0   2016-04-01 00:31:46.000
1   2016-04-01 00:31:46.000
1   2016-04-01 00:35:01.000
1   2016-04-01 00:40:07.000
1   2016-04-01 00:44:46.000
1   2016-04-01 00:49:52.000
1   2016-04-01 00:54:58.000
1   2016-04-01 01:00:04.000
1   2016-04-01 01:01:28.000
0   2016-04-01 01:01:28.000
0   2016-04-01 01:05:10.000
0   2016-04-01 01:09:49.000
```

And i want to count the seconds where value is 1 (switch ON) PER DAY, here is the deal; When the timeStamp repeats it means that there was a change from 0 to 1 or viceversa in the switch value, I already had many aproches like:

```
Q1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS id,
Value, Timestamp
FROM Q2
GROUP BY idVBox, sensorType, sensorSubtype, timeStamp
HAVING COUNT(TimeStamp) > 1)

Then:

SELECT A.Value, DATEDIFF(SECOND,A.TimeStamp,B.TimeStamp)
FROM Q1 AS A
INNER JOIN Q1 AS B
ON B.ID = A.ID + 1
AND B.ID%2 = 0
```

Then Group by and Sum, but here the problem is that i don't know if the value comes in 1 or 0 from the past day, and the switch can change it's state quick and never get an actual value of it's actual state. Any other idea?

Comment: Are you counting the seconds between off and on? How can it be turned on and then on again? I'm missing something. You must be recording multiple switches. How many switches are there in total?

Comment: Yeah, i want to count the time between On and Off where in the middle of the sequence are only rows with switch ON (value = 1),  There is only ona switch, when the timeStamps repeats it's when the switch gets switched.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do, is add a dummy sensor state switch into your set at the beginning of the day before you start your calculation.

The extra records added are:

```
0, '2016-04-01 00:00:00'
1, '2016-04-01 00:00:00' -- This is conditional on the first record in your set having a value of 1
```

The overall query is below
Note: in order to determine what record is actually the first in sequence I used "ID" column.

```
;WITH Q0 AS(
    -- Inserts a new record ( 0, '2016-04-01 00:00:00' ) to the beginning of the day
    SELECT TOP 1 0 AS Value, CONVERT( DATETIME, CONVERT( DATE, LogDate )) AS LogDate
    FROM #SwitchLog
    UNION ALL
    -- Inserts a new record ( 1, '2016-04-01 00:00:00' ) to the beginning of the day when the first record has Value = 1
    SELECT Value, CONVERT( DATETIME, CONVERT( DATE, LogDate )) AS LogDate
    FROM
        ( SELECT TOP 1 ID, Value, LogDate
        FROM #SwitchLog
        ORDER BY LogDate ASC, ID ASC ) AS DummyRecord --<-- NOTE: the use of a table ID column
    WHERE Value = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Value, LogDate
    FROM #SwitchLog
)
,
Q1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LogDate) AS id,
SUM( Value ) AS Value, LogDate
FROM Q0
GROUP BY LogDate
HAVING COUNT(LogDate) > 1)

SELECT A.Value, DATEDIFF(SECOND,A.LogDate,B.LogDate) AS Total
FROM Q1 AS A
INNER JOIN Q1 AS B
ON B.ID = A.ID + 1 AND B.ID%2 = 0
```

Output:

```
Value       Total
----------- -----------
1           69
1           1782
1           1782
```

Same approach should be used to insert dummy record(s) at the end of the period/day ((day + 1) 00:00:00) to cater for situations where sensor value is 1 at the end of the day.

Comment: @Jorge, lets see if someone else can submit a better answer, if nothing else comes up, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL Server 2012 then you could make good use of the LAG() function.
First, join the table on duplicate dates where value=1. Next, calculate difference between the on and the previous on. Finally, sum it up.

NOTE : The LAG() will return null for first on of the day.

```
SELECT 
    Seconds=SUM(X.Seconds)
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        Seconds=DATEDIFF(SECOND,LAG(T1.TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY T1.TimeStamp),T1.TimeStamp)    
    FROM
        MyTable T1
        INNER JOIN MyTable T2 ON T2.TimeStamp=T1.TimeStamp AND T1.Value<>T2.Value
    WHERE
        T1.Value=1
)AS X
```

Comment: I meant to say that it counts seconds for both 0s and 1s

Comment: I see now. You would have to do another rank in there to get that. I was going for a compact approach and did not catch that.