# SQL construct and renew date intervals for entities based on daily incoming data

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal

I have a daily incoming data with following format:
`(id, dat, state, val)` where `id` is unique entity, `dat` is date (i.e. ISO 'yyyy-MM-dd'), `state` is a state of an entity, `val` is a value of an entity at this state.

I need to transform it into data like that format: `(id, state, val, dat1, dat2, month)` where `dat1` and `dat2` are datestamps between which the entity `id` has state `state` with `val` value within month.

I'm struggling to find out a correct way to collect and persist data like this format. I understand that solution must meet the following requirements:

1) If `id` has changed his `state` from `st1` to `st2` in new daily data(i.e. on 2017-01-27), there should be a row with closed period like that:

```
(id=1, state=st1, val=2.5, dat1='2017-01-15', dat2='2017-01-26', month='2017-01-01')
```

and a row for state `st2` like that:

```
(id=1, state=st2, val=5.5, dat1='2017-01-27', dat2='2017-01-31', month='2017-01-01')
```

2) If on 2017-02-14 there is a new `id` for a table, there should be an inserted row like that:

`(id=2, state=st3, val=1.5, dat1='2017-02-01', dat2='2017-02-28', month='2017-02-01')`, 
so if there is a new id in daily data and this id doesn't exist in previous periods we put his birth date as beginning of the period and hold the closing date as end of month until there is a change of state of this id within February month.

3) A table should be designed in the way allowing having history of table versions before insert\update a new daily piece of data (bi-temporal table?) in order to have an opportunity to discard wrong data and rollback.

4) There should be a query for table which is able to detect overlapping date intervals of the same ID (force ID integrity over time).

5) There should be some necessary indexes for this kind of data. Id should be a foreign key.

6) Should there be a trigger which works when a new piece of data has arrived into load-table and makes operations described in 1),2),3) ?

Could anyone tell the literature or known approaches for this kind of tasks?
I believe it is solved task but I couldn't determine the proper name of data model and find any clear examples for that kind of data.

Comment: so, every time a new data comes, assuming this always happens in time order, the following should happen: 1 - a new row is inserted with dat2 = last day of the current month; 2 - if this month already had this id, its dat2 should be updated to new dat1 minus 1 day. In case a row is removed there should be an update on the previous row with the same id, setting it's dat2 to that of the row removed.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mssql2012, but oracle is interesting too

Answer (score 0):

Below code updates Entity state table based on "Daily Data".
I have created my own sample data, that to the best of my understanding fits your requirements.

```
CREATE TABLE #DailyData( id INT, [state] VARCHAR( 10 ), val FLOAT, dat1 DATETIME )
CREATE TABLE #EntityState( id INT, [state] VARCHAR( 10 ), val FLOAT, dat1 DATETIME, dat2 DATETIME, [month] DATETIME )
INSERT INTO #EntityState
SELECT 1, 'st2', 4.6, '01-Jul-2017', '08-Jul-2017', '01-Jul-2017' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'st1', 1.2, '09-Jul-2017', '31-Jul-2017', '01-Jul-2017' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'st1', 2.2, '08-Jul-2017', '31-Jul-2017', '01-Jul-2017'

INSERT INTO #DailyData
SELECT 1, 'st3', 5.6, '15-Jul-2017' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'st2', 4.6, '01-Aug-2017' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'st2', 2.5, '10-Jul-2017'


SELECT 'Before', * FROM #EntityState
;WITH Q0 AS(
    -- Insert current state
    SELECT id, [state], val, dat1
    FROM
    ( SELECT id, [state], val, dat1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dat1 DESC ) AS LatestDate
    FROM #EntityState ) AS CurrentState
    WHERE LatestDate = 1
    UNION ALL
    -- Combine with Daily Import
    SELECT id, [state], val, dat1
    FROM #DailyData
)
,
-- Add Date order column
Q1 AS (
    SELECT id, [state], val, dat1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dat1 ASC ) AS DateOrder
    FROM Q0
    )
-- Merge new Entity states with Existing
MERGE INTO #EntityState AS T
    USING
            -- New Entity states 
            ( SELECT Prev.id, Prev.[state], Prev.val, Prev.dat1, Next.dat1 AS dat2
            FROM Q1 AS Prev
                LEFT JOIN Q1 AS Next ON Prev.id = Next.id AND Prev.DateOrder + 1 = Next.DateOrder ) AS S
        ON T.id = S.id AND T.dat1 = S.dat1 AND T.[state] = S.[state]
    -- Update dat2 on last day's state
    WHEN MATCHED AND T.dat2 = EOMONTH( T.dat1 )
        THEN UPDATE 
            SET T.dat2 = S.dat2
    -- Add new Entity State
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT( id, state, val, dat1, dat2, [month] )
            VALUES( S.id, S.state, S.val, S.dat1, ISNULL( S.dat2, EOMONTH( S.dat1 )),
                    DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, 0, S.dat1 ), 0 ));

SELECT 'After', * FROM #EntityState
```

This code was adapted from:
[Count seconds on switch interval SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401369/count-seconds-on-switch-interval-sql-server/37403330#37403330)