# Transform Dates into Date Range in MYSQL---how to handle gaps in the dates

Tags: mysql, date, gaps-and-islands

I am looking for a help in transforming below data into the required output. We have data at Item,LOC DAY level data which needs to be transformed to Item,Loc Date Range to reduce the number of records in the table and for other requirements.

```
Item        LOC  RP_DATE    RP_IND   
1003785256  543 2016-11-05  Y
1003785256  543 2016-11-06  Y
1003785256  543 2016-11-07  Y
1003785256  543 2016-11-09  Y
1003785256  543 2016-11-10  Y
1003790365  150 2016-11-05  Y
1003797790  224 2016-11-05  Y
1003797790  224 2016-11-06  Y
1003797790  224 2016-11-07  Y
1003797790  224 2016-11-08  Y
```

Required Output:

```
Item        LOC  RP_ST_DATE    RP_END_DATE   
1003785256  543 2016-11-05   2016-11-07
1003785256  543 2016-11-09   2016-11-10
1003790365  150 2016-11-05   2016-11-05
1003797790  224 2016-11-05   2016-11-08
```

Comment: select epm_sku_idnt,loc_idnt ,min(rp_date) ,max(rp_date) from RP_SKU_LOC group by epm_sku_idnt,loc_idnt;  i tried this but it doesnt work for the scenario where there are gaps

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979192/sql-construct-and-renew-date-intervals-for-entities-based-on-daily-incoming-data/44997259#44997259 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401369/count-seconds-on-switch-interval-sql-server/37403330#37403330. Note these answers are for SQL Server.

Comment: You also need to clearly describe in your question what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to transform the data which is at DAY level to a DATE RANGE level as shown in the expected output.

Comment: @Harsha you seem to be omitting a key requirement from your question: how to handle gaps in the dates. One of your comments make a hint, but your question still does not specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is for MySQL. It uses a combination variables within an ordered subquery to establish a common starting date for each "range". The CROSS JOIN is used just to initialize the variables, it does not alter the number of rows. Once the common starting date is established then it becomes a simple group by query in the outer query.

```
SELECT Item, LOC, RP_IND, dr_begin, MAX(RP_DATE) dr_end
FROM (
  SELECT
         mytable.*
       , @fin := CONVERT(IF(@item<=>item AND @loc<=>loc AND DATEDIFF(rp_date, @d)=1, @fin, rp_date), DATE) AS dr_begin
       , @item := item
       , @loc := loc
       , @d := rp_date
  FROM     mytable CROSS JOIN (SELECT @item:=NULL, @loc:=NULL, @d:=NULL, @fin := NULL) AS init
  ORDER BY item, loc, rp_date
  ) d
GROUP BY  Item, LOC, RP_IND, dr_begin
;

+----+------------+-----+--------+------------+---------------------+
|    |    Item    | LOC | RP_IND |  dr_begin  |       dr_end        |
+----+------------+-----+--------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1003785256 | 543 | Y      | 2016-11-05 | 07.11.2016 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 1003785256 | 543 | Y      | 2016-11-09 | 10.11.2016 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 1003790365 | 150 | Y      | 2016-11-05 | 05.11.2016 00:00:00 |
|  4 | 1003797790 | 224 | Y      | 2016-11-05 | 08.11.2016 00:00:00 |
+----+------------+-----+--------+------------+---------------------+
```

Note *<=>* [returns 1 if both operands are NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

See the query working at: http://rextester.com/SEYG96251

```
#drop table mytable;

CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Item    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LOC     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,RP_DATE DATE  NOT NULL
  ,RP_IND  VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003785256,543,'2016-11-05','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003785256,543,'2016-11-06','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003785256,543,'2016-11-07','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003785256,543,'2016-11-09','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003785256,543,'2016-11-10','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003790365,150,'2016-11-05','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003797790,224,'2016-11-05','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003797790,224,'2016-11-06','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003797790,224,'2016-11-07','Y');
INSERT INTO mytable(Item,LOC,RP_DATE,RP_IND) VALUES (1003797790,224,'2016-11-08','Y');
```

Comment: This logic works fine when table data is around 10M... but I have a table with 500M to 1B records and this query hangs and gives me an error asking to increase heap size.... I increased the heap size to 32GB and still the same error.

Comment: @rsh  v.regretable for sure, but MySQL prior to version 8.?  lacks `window functions` when 'row_number() over ()` is to become available. If your db supports row_number use that. Regret to say that any alternatives will be ugly for your v.large table. Mind you as I've not seen or used MySQL v8 yet. Who knows how well that will implement the window functions at that scale. Many other dbs already have this capability.