# Mysql - Select hour that not use in a day

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database that have a relation. I use MySQL. Basically, I created an app to manage 'Futsal's Field Order' So, here we go :

The first table is named Lapangan means "Field in Indonesian" :

```
mysql> SELECT id,nama_lapangan FROM lapangan;
+----+---------------+
| id | nama_lapangan |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Lap 01        |
|  2 | Lap 02        |
|  3 | Lap 03        |
+----+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And The Second Table is Booking : ,

```
mysql> SELECT id, nomor_booking, date_booking, date_end_booking, lapangan_id FROM `yfutsal`.`booking` LIMIT 1000;
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| id | nomor_booking | date_booking        | date_end_booking    | lapangan_id |
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|  1 |             1 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00 | 2017-07-16 12:00:00 |           1 |
|  2 |             2 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00 | 2017-07-16 16:00:00 |           3 |
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Here is the problem.

For example, The Owner start at 08.00 AND end in 23.00.

It means,

1. lap 1 is not available on 10.00 - 12.00
2. lap 3 is not available on 15.00 - 16.00.

The goal is, I want to display the Lapangan (field) that available with hour field, based hour that not include from case above.

So, the cashier can choice it. Something like this :

```
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
| id | nama_lapangan |   Available Start    |    Available End      |
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Lap 01        |  2017-07-16 08:00:00 |   2017-07-16 09:59:00 |
|  1 | Lap 01        |  2017-07-16 12:01:00 |   2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
|  2 | Lap 02        |  2017-07-16 08:00:00 |   2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
|  3 | Lap 03        |  2017-07-16 08:00:00 |   2017-07-16 14:59:00 |
|  3 | Lap 03        |  2017-07-16 16:01:00 |   2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

From bottom of my heart, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather tricky goal without window functions (which MySQL 5.7 doesn't have). It is feasible, even if it isn't easy to understand.

For the sake of ease, I've used an extra table I've called `parameters`:

```
CREATE TABLE parameters
(
    start_date_time DATETIME,
    end_date_time DATETIME
) ;
INSERT INTO parameters 
VALUES ('2017-07-16 08:00', '2017-07-16 23:00') ;
```

The idea is, for a given lapangan (field), if one day there's just *one* booking (start_booking_1,end_booking_1), we will get two available periods:

```
start_date_time .. start_booking_1      <- first period
end_booking_1   .. end_date_time        <- 2
```

If one day there are *two* bookings (start_booking_1, end_booking_1) and (start_booking_2, end_booking_2), sorted, we'll have:

```
start_date_time .. start_booking_1      <- first period
end_booking_1   .. start_booking_2      <- 2
end_booking_2   .. end_date_time        <- 3
```

So, we need to distinguish the first period from the rest:

First free segment can be computed with:

```
-- first free period
SELECT
    lapangan.id, parameters.start_date_time AS available_start, 
    coalesce( (SELECT date_start_booking
                 FROM booking b
                WHERE b.lapangan_id = lapangan.id
              ORDER BY b.date_start_booking ASC
                LIMIT 1
               ), parameters.end_date_time) AS available_end
FROM
    lapangan, parameters
```

NOTE: the way to search for `start_booking_1` is the awful subquery. If it doesn't return a value, we'll go to the `end_date_time`.

The intermediate (and last) periods, are computed with:

```
-- 2..n free periods
SELECT
    lapangan.id, 
    b1.date_end_booking AS available_start, 
    coalesce ( (SELECT date_start_booking
                  FROM booking b2
                 WHERE b2.lapangan_id = b1.lapangan_id 
                     AND b2.date_start_booking >= b1.date_end_booking
              ORDER BY b2.date_start_booking ASC
                 LIMIT 1), 
               (SELECT parameters.end_date_time 
                  FROM parameters)
    ) AS avilable_end
FROM
    lapangan
    JOIN booking b1 ON b1.lapangan_id = lapangan.id
```

You'll have to put everything together, and take care of possible *empty* periods. Then you'll get

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    lapangan.id, lapangan.nama_lapangan, av.available_start, av.available_end AS available_end
FROM
    (    
    -- first free period
    SELECT
        lapangan.id, parameters.start_date_time AS available_start, 
        coalesce( (SELECT date_start_booking
                     FROM booking b
                    WHERE b.lapangan_id = lapangan.id
                  ORDER BY b.date_start_booking ASC
                    LIMIT 1
                   ), parameters.end_date_time) AS available_end
    FROM
        lapangan, parameters

    UNION  
    -- 2..n free periods
    SELECT
        lapangan.id, 
        b1.date_end_booking AS available_start, 
        coalesce ( (SELECT date_start_booking
                      FROM booking b2
                     WHERE b2.lapangan_id = b1.lapangan_id 
                         AND b2.date_start_booking >= b1.date_end_booking
                  ORDER BY b2.date_start_booking ASC
                     LIMIT 1), 
                   (SELECT parameters.end_date_time 
                      FROM parameters)
        ) AS avilable_end
    FROM
        lapangan
        JOIN booking b1 ON b1.lapangan_id = lapangan.id
    ) AS av
    JOIN lapangan ON lapangan.id = av.id
WHERE
    -- Ignore empty segments
    av.available_start < av.available_end
ORDER BY
    lapangan.id, available_start ;
```

Which will give you the intended result.

```
id | nama_lapangan | available_start     | available_end      
-: | :------------ | :------------------ | :------------------
 1 | Lap 01        | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00
 1 | Lap 01        | 2017-07-16 12:00:00 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00
 2 | Lap 02        | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00
 3 | Lap 03        | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00
 3 | Lap 03        | 2017-07-16 16:00:00 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00
```

Note that I have *not* subtracted 1 minute or 1 second from the start or end. Assume that your periods are considered:

```
start <= available_time < end
```

or, in range terminology

```
[start, end)
```

If you really need to subtract 1 second, do it in the first line of the select.

You can check everything (with some step-by-step approach to reaching the solution) at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4a42ef63946f0a2729bd4577ebf87bae)*

---

Side Note: this is much easier if you use a DB that knows how to use the `LEAD` or `LAG` window functions.

Comment: Crikey, are you sure that it needs to be as complicated as all that?

Comment: Thanks, it looks so complicated. 
I did not think that the problem got that far.

Comment: Btw, I have try your approach. I think the approach need more flexible. Beacuse the query is dependant based the 'parameters' table which is store just one day. It's not user friendly if cashier have to update in each day.

Comment: This is complicated because of the *lack* of lag and lead functions. If they were present, it is straightforward. The *parameters* table is actually an *opening times* table, which should be part of the definition because you don't necessarily open every day at the same time. The query *will* work with a few tweaks (some extra ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1) when parameters is a full calendar. *It is left as an exercise for the reader*

Comment: @joanolo, When I user your suggestion, I got this problem when I have a case like this, Let say, a today is 17-07-2017, But customer want to booking on 20-07-2017. The query give a lot of records between 17-02-2017 AND 20-07-2017. Cashier just the booking on 20-07-2017 .

Comment: Any suggestion again, still stuck here

Comment: Put your case at dbfiddle, and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of this problem is to generate rows of data where there isn't anything stored. In other words you have the hours that are booked stored, but not the hours which remain un-booked. So you need a way to generate these. While there are several alternatives to this a simple option is to use a Cartesian product to do this.

Here I have opted to store the hours of operation in a table as a set of integers 8 to 23 (maybe 8 to 22 depending on your intention). This can then be used in a CROSS JOIN (to produce a Cartesian product) on any given date of all hours for all fields (nama_lapangan). Once this is generated we can LEFT JOIN all the available hours to these which are already booked, and then where there is no current related booking (IS NULL) we determine the available hours for that day.

**DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE OpenHours
    (`StartAt` int)
;

INSERT INTO OpenHours     (`StartAt`)
VALUES
    (8),    (9),    (10),    (11),    (12),    (13),    (14),    (15),
    (16),    (17),    (18),    (19),    (20),    (21),    (22),    (23)
;

CREATE TABLE lapangan
    (`id` int, `nama_lapangan` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO lapangan     (`id`, `nama_lapangan`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Lap 01'), (2, 'Lap 02'), (3, 'Lap 03')
;


CREATE TABLE yfutsal
    (`id` int, `nomor_booking` int, `date_booking` datetime, `date_end_booking` datetime, `lapangan_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO yfutsal
    (`id`, `nomor_booking`, `date_booking`, `date_end_booking`, `lapangan_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-07-16 10:00:00', '2017-07-16 12:00:00', 1),
    (2, 2, '2017-07-16 15:00:00', '2017-07-16 16:00:00', 3)
;
```

**QUERY**

```
set @dt := str_to_date('2017-07-16','%Y-%m-%d');

select
    l.id
  , l.nama_lapangan
  , date_add(@dt,INTERVAL h.StartAt HOUR) AvailStartHr
  , date_add(@dt,INTERVAL h.StartAt+1 HOUR) AvailEndHr
from lapangan l
cross join OpenHours h
left join yfutsal y on l.id = y.lapangan_id
                   and date_add(@dt,INTERVAL h.StartAt HOUR) between date_booking and date_end_booking
where y.date_booking IS NULL
order by l.nama_lapangan, AvailStartHr
;
```

**RESULT**

```
| id | nama_lapangan |        AvailStartHr |          AvailEndHr |
|----|---------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-16 09:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 09:00:00 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 13:00:00 | 2017-07-16 14:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 14:00:00 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00 | 2017-07-16 16:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 16:00:00 | 2017-07-16 17:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 17:00:00 | 2017-07-16 18:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 18:00:00 | 2017-07-16 19:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 19:00:00 | 2017-07-16 20:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 20:00:00 | 2017-07-16 21:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 21:00:00 | 2017-07-16 22:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 22:00:00 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00 | 2017-07-17 00:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-16 09:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 09:00:00 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00 | 2017-07-16 11:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 11:00:00 | 2017-07-16 12:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 12:00:00 | 2017-07-16 13:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 13:00:00 | 2017-07-16 14:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 14:00:00 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00 | 2017-07-16 16:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 16:00:00 | 2017-07-16 17:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 17:00:00 | 2017-07-16 18:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 18:00:00 | 2017-07-16 19:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 19:00:00 | 2017-07-16 20:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 20:00:00 | 2017-07-16 21:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 21:00:00 | 2017-07-16 22:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 22:00:00 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00 | 2017-07-17 00:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-16 09:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 09:00:00 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00 | 2017-07-16 11:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 11:00:00 | 2017-07-16 12:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 12:00:00 | 2017-07-16 13:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 13:00:00 | 2017-07-16 14:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 14:00:00 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 17:00:00 | 2017-07-16 18:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 18:00:00 | 2017-07-16 19:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 19:00:00 | 2017-07-16 20:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 20:00:00 | 2017-07-16 21:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 21:00:00 | 2017-07-16 22:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 22:00:00 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 23:00:00 | 2017-07-17 00:00:00 |
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/775f36/4

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try first.

Comment: there is a mistake I used an incorrect field in the join to bookings, Corrected now see previous http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/775f36/3 and now http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/775f36/4

Comment: Dear @Used_By_Already, I have show the data from query above to my client. Sadly, They don't like it. They are still need like my question.

Comment: Now you know how to get all available hours you can summarize them. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023270/transform-dates-into-date-range-in-mysql-how-to-handle-gaps-in-the-dates/45024518#45024518  for how to summarize in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

In the former answer you learn how to generate the required available hours row by row. Once you have that data available, then it can be summarized into ranges using the following technique for MySQL:

```
set @dt := str_to_date('2017-07-16','%Y-%m-%d')

SELECT id, nama_lapangan, AvailStart, MAX(AvailEndHr) AvailEndHr
FROM (
  SELECT
         mytable.*
       , @fin := IF(@lid<=>id AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, @d, AvailStartHr)=1, @fin, AvailStartHr) AS AvailStart
       , @lid := id
       , @d := AvailStartHr
  FROM (
      select
          l.id
        , l.nama_lapangan
        , date_add(@dt,INTERVAL h.StartAt HOUR) AvailStartHr
        , date_add(@dt,INTERVAL h.StartAt+1 HOUR) AvailEndHr
      from lapangan l
      cross join OpenHours h
      left join yfutsal y on l.id = y.lapangan_id
                         and date_add(@dt,INTERVAL h.StartAt HOUR) between date_booking and date_end_booking
      where y.date_booking IS NULL
     ) mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @lid:=NULL, @d:=NULL, @fin:= NOW()) AS init
  ORDER BY id, AvailStartHr
  ) d
GROUP BY  id, nama_lapangan, AvailStart
```

**Results** [see sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/481635/1/1):

```
| id | nama_lapangan |          AvailStart |          AvailEndHr |
|----|---------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00 |
|  1 |        Lap 01 | 2017-07-16 13:00:00 | 2017-07-17 00:00:00 |
|  2 |        Lap 02 | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-17 00:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 08:00:00 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00 |
|  3 |        Lap 03 | 2017-07-16 17:00:00 | 2017-07-17 00:00:00 |
```

Also see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023270/transform-dates-into-date-range-in-mysql-how-to-handle-gaps-in-the-dates/45024518#45024518) on a similar theme.